# Sinatra PUT method not updating

Tags: javascript, ruby, json, angularjs, sinatra

My Sinatra method is receiving JSON correctly, but for some reason not saving it. It's being routed from Angular JS, so I'm wondering if one of the following could be the issue:

- The routing to Sinatra is incorrect, however the JSON displays from a puts inside the Sinatra route
- The database is not accepting the converted JSON (not sure why)
- The JSON is incorrectly parsed, however the technique for parsing is the same within the rest of my app.

I've posted the code below, if you have any ideas as to why it's not working that would be fantastic.

Many thanks.

app.rb

```
#edit download
put '/view1/downloadedit' do
  @download = Download.get(1)  #1 for testing, will be downloadID
  data= JSON.parse(request.body.read)
  puts @download
  puts data
  if
    @download.update(data)
    status 201
    puts "edit saved okay"
  else
    status 201
    puts "edit failed to SAVE"
  end
end
```

controllers.js (Angular)

```
  // a scope function to edit a record
  $scope.updateinfo = function(downloadID) {
    id = downloadID
    var result = $scope.items.filter(function( items ) {
        return items.downloadID == id;
    });
    console.log(result);
    updatedata = $scope.items
    $http({
        method : 'PUT',
        url :  '/view1/downloadedit',
        data : result
    });
    $scope.loadData();
 };
}]);
```

Feedback from terminal showing correct JSON output from puts in app.rb

```
  angular connection working
  {"downloadID"=>1, "PageID"=>"1", "title"=>"nmnbm", "dlLink"=>"bnmnbm", "imgSrc"=>"mnbmnb", "caption"=>"aaa", "dlLive"=>1, "createdAt"=>nil}
```

Download class

```
#class download
class Download
include DataMapper::Resource
property :downloadID, Serial
property :PageID, String
property :title, String
property :dlLink, String
property :imgSrc, String
property :caption, String
property :dlLive, Integer
property :createdAt, DateTime
end
```

MySQL table structure for downloads, exported as CSV

```
<table_structure name="downloads">
    <field field="download_id" type="int(10) unsigned" null="NO" key="PRI" default="<null>" extra="auto_increment" />
    <field field="page_id" type="varchar(50)" null="YES" key="" default="<null>" extra="" />
    <field field="title" type="varchar(50)" null="YES" key="" default="<null>" extra="" />
    <field field="dl_link" type="varchar(50)" null="YES" key="" default="<null>" extra="" />
    <field field="img_src" type="varchar(50)" null="YES" key="" default="<null>" extra="" />
    <field field="caption" type="longtext" null="YES" key="" default="<null>" extra="" />
    <field field="dl_live" type="int(1)" null="YES" key="" default="<null>" extra="" />
    <field field="created_at" type="datetime" null="YES" key="" default="<null>" extra="" />

    <options name="downloads" engine="InnoDB" version="10" row_format="Compact" rows="8" avg_row_length="2048" data_length="16384" max_data_length="0" index_length="0" data_free="4194304" create_time="2013-11-04 17:26:56" update_time="<null>" collation="utf8_general_ci" create_options="" comment="" />
</table_structure>
```

Comment: Which ORM library are you using?

Comment: @joews using datamapper, I'm still looking for a solution. Many thanks

Comment: Could you post your Download class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needs to be passed the :id attribute to update.

```
put '/view1/downloadedit/:id' do
  data = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
  edit_id = data[0]["downloadID"]
  p data
  p edit_id
  @download_edit = Download.get(params[:id])
  p @download_edit
  success = @download_edit.update(:title => data[0]['title'],
                                  :caption => data[0]['caption'],
                                  :dlLink => data[0]['dlLink'],
                                  :imgSrc => data[0]['imgSrc'])
  if success
    status 201
    puts 'edit saved okay'
  else
    status 201
    puts 'edit failed to SAVE'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that Datamapper does not know which property to use as the primary key. Try using this in your Download class:

```
property :downloadID, Serial, key: true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but still it is not being saved to the database.

Comment: Does a download with id = 1 definitely exist in the database? And are you getting an exception, or just nothing saved to the db?

Comment: it does exist, and nope, no exception.. it's very strange

Comment: Can you post the output of @download.errors after the failed update?

Comment: @download.errors -> #<DataMapper::Validations::ValidationErrors:0x007f866b894ce0>

Comment: #<DataMapper::Validations::ValidationErrors:0x007f8bdba60748 @resource=#<Download @downloadID=1 @PageID="1" @title="nmnbm" @dlLink="bnmnbm" @imgSrc="mnbmnb" @caption="mbnmnb" @dlLive=1 @createdAt=nil>, @errors={}>

Comment: OK, there don't seem to be any errors. Afraid I'm out of ideas!

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. The only thing I'm thinking is that the database field names are slightly different to the class names that it's being posted from. However Sinatra reads from the database and creates new records without problems :/

Comment: as seen in the mysql table structure posted

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem POSTing and PUTing JSON requests into sinatra.

I overcame it by adding this to my config.ru file. Got it from here

```
require 'rack/parser'

use Rack::Parser, content_types: {
  'application/json' => Proc.new { |body| ::MultiJson.decode body }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately that didn't sort the issue :/

Answer (score 0):

Also your code

```
put '/view1/downloadedit' do
  puts 'angular connection working'
  ng_params = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
  puts ng_params
  @download = Download.update(ng_params)
end
```

should probably be

```
put '/view1/downloadedit' do
  # Below line shoudlnt be needed if the config.ru rack/parser works properly
  #ng_params = JSON.parse(request.body.read)

  @download = Download.where(id: params[:downloadID])

  # Maybe add an update! to blow up the update with validations to see if that is why data is not saving.
  unless @download.update(ng_params)
    return 'Error message'
  end
  @download
end
```

or something like that

Comment: It's parsing the JSON okay with rack/parser, however it's still getting the 500 error. I'm just trying to work out why? I'm thinking it still maybe the route?

Comment: As I'm using datamapper instead of ActiveRecord I think the syntax is slightly different, I have to use Download.get(primary key) but even when explicitly stating 1 as the primary key it still throws a 500